# Detecting outliers from a list

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, list, outliers

I want to detect and store outliers from a list and this is what I am doing

Code:

```
def outliers(y,thresh=3.5):
    
    m = np.median(y)
    abs_dev = np.abs(y - m)
    left_mad = np.median(abs_dev[y <= m])
    right_mad = np.median(abs_dev[y >= m])
    y_mad = left_mad * np.ones(len(y))
    y_mad[y > m] = right_mad
    modified_z_score = 0.6745 * abs_dev / y_mad
    modified_z_score[y == m] = 0
    return modified_z_score > thresh

bids = [5000,5500,4500,1000,15000,5200,4900]

z = outliers(bids)
bidd = np.array(bids)
out_liers = bidd[z]
```

This gives results as:

```
out_liers = array([ 1000, 15000])
```

Is there a better way to do this, where I don't get the results in array but in a list?
Also please can someone explain me why we used

> thresh=3.5
>
> modified_z_score = 0.6745 * abs_dev / y_mad

Comment: If you need a list instead of the numpy array, numpy arrays conveniently provide a `tolist` function: `out_liers.tolist()`. Your other queries are best answered by the original author of the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works:

```
def outliers_modified_z_score(ys, threshold=3.5):
    ys_arr = np.array(ys)
    median_y = np.median(ys_arr)
    median_absolute_deviation_y = np.median(np.abs(ys_arr - median_y))
    modified_z_scores = 0.6745 * (ys_arr - median_y) / median_absolute_deviation_y
    return (ys_arr[np.abs(modified_z_scores) > threshold]).tolist()
```

Comment: Thanks a ton! Also could you explain the values 3.5 and 0.6745

Comment: 0.6745 is because `E[MAD] = 0.6745 * sigma` for normally distributed variables. 

Try: `x = np.random.normal(size=100000000)` then
`print(np.median(np.abs(x - np.median(x))).mean() / x.std())`

3.5 is also found empirically by Iglewicz and Hoaglin (the creators of the outlier test). See: https://hwbdocuments.env.nm.gov/Los%20Alamos%20National%20Labs/TA%2054/11587.pdf

Answer (score 1):

That's because you are using `numpy` function. Default type used there is `numpy.ndarray`, which speeds up the computations. In the case you just need a list as output argument, use `tolist()` method.

```py
z = outliers(bids)
bidd = np.array(bids)
out_liers = bidd[z].tolist()
```